# Stuck on a proof involving the floor of a ratio of natural logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So, I'm working on a proof of a personal problem that I solved years ago unrigorously, and am now trying to rigorously prove. The problem I have is as follows:

Given some $v\in\Bbb Z$, $v\ge2$, find a formula giving $m\in\Bbb Z$, $m>0$ such that

$$\frac{(2+\sqrt{5})^m-(2-\sqrt{5})^m}{\sqrt{5}}\le v<\frac{(2+\sqrt{5})^{m+1}-(2-\sqrt{5})^{m+1}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Now, if - as I wholly suspect - the $(2-\sqrt{5})^m$ and $(2-\sqrt{5})^{m+1}$ terms can be ignored due to their lack of effect on the final result (as $|2-\sqrt{5}|<\frac{1}{2}$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}|(2-\sqrt{5})^m|=0$), then we have:

$$m\le \frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5})}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}<m+1$$

which implies that:

$$m=\lfloor\frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5})}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}\rfloor$$

which certainly seems to work empirically. However, the difficulty I'm having is in proving that that $(2-\sqrt{5})^m$ term can be dropped since we're taking the floor of the final result. Boiling it down, I need to prove that:

$$\lfloor\frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5})}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5}+(2-\sqrt{5})^m)}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}\rfloor$$

for all $v\in\Bbb Z$, $v\ge2$ and $m\in\Bbb Z$, $m>0$ (as above), and I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how best to go about it. Any pointers in the correct direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$v = \frac{(2+\sqrt{5})^m-(2-\sqrt{5})^m}{\sqrt{5}}$$
with even $m$. Then
$$
(2+\sqrt{5})^{m-1}<(2+\sqrt{5})^m-1<v\sqrt{5}< (2+\sqrt{5})^m.
$$
which implies
$$m-1\le \frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5})}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}<m.$$
Therefore,
$$\left\lfloor\frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5})}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}\right\rfloor=m-1,$$
and your claim is false, unfortunately.

---

If, however, both inequalities are strict,
$$
F_m:=\frac{(2+\sqrt{5})^m-(2-\sqrt{5})^m}{\sqrt{5}}< v<\frac{(2+\sqrt{5})^{m+1}-(2-\sqrt{5})^{m+1}}{\sqrt{5}},$$
then (knowing that $F_m$ is integer) $F_m+1\le v\le F_{m+1}-1$. Therefore,
$$
(2+\sqrt5)^m < \sqrt{5}F_{m+1} + \sqrt{5}\le v\sqrt{5}\le F_{m+1}-\sqrt{5} <(2+\sqrt5)^{m+1},
$$
whence
$$\left\lfloor\frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5})}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}\right\rfloor=m.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you got to

$$(2+\sqrt{5})^m-1<v\sqrt{5}< (2+\sqrt{5})^m$$

by setting

$$v = \frac{(2+\sqrt{5})^m-(2-\sqrt{5})^m}{\sqrt{5}}$$

I'm afraid I'm not certain I understand how you arrived thereat.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I should refrain from thinking before my morning coffee. :)

Comment: @JeremyHolland, no problem. Ask if something is not clear.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you derived

$$m-1\le \frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5})}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}<m$$

based on

$$(2+\sqrt{5})^m-1<v\sqrt{5}< (2+\sqrt{5})^m$$

I'm afraid I'm not able to see how you got there.

Comment: I believe I understand that

$$(2+\sqrt{5})^{m-1}<(2+\sqrt{5})^{m}-1\quad\forall\ m\in\Bbb Z,m>0$$

and so

$$m-1<\frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5})}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}<m.$$

Is it therefore logically correct to be able to make the looser assertion

$$m-1\le\frac{\ln{(v\sqrt{5})}}{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}<m?$$

Comment: @JeremyHolland, done.